# Node Redis cached data seems to randomly disappear

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm using Redis to store data from an API with a TTL of a 7 days.

Here's some psuedo of what I'm doing to set the data.

First I check if the data is in Redis.

```
for(let i=0; i< requestedData.length; i++){ 
    let exists = await client.exists(cacheKey);
    if(!exists) {
        // queue to be fetched
    }
}
```

After the data is fetched I store it.

```
for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++){ 
    await client.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(dataToStore), {
         EX: 604800,
    });
}
```

This seems to work well as when I validate the cache keys through Redis-cli everything is there. The problem comes the next time I attempt to get the data from Redis.

Redis will inconsistently have data disappear from the cache. It's not overwritten, it's just gone. Normally I'd expect ~800 keys, but there will randomly be 450, 300, 575, etc. Even though the only time the cache is used at all in subsequent requests, it's to check if the data already exists (which it does) as shown above in the psuedo. I've debugged for hours trying to figure out what's going on and I'm wondering if it's something out of my control.

Does `exists()` remove keys sometimes?

I'm using an M1 macbook.. is there an issue with compatibility with Redis?

I've checked if max_memory is being hit and its only about 10% used.

If anyone has had this issue before and has managed to figure it out your input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Exists, should not remove an existing key. Check if other part of your code, maybe tries to fetch and remove from Redis.

Comment: @YoavNaaman ive gone as far as removing the exists call so the only interaction with redis is a `get(cacheKey)` and the keys still disappear. Before requests 796 keys, after request 487 keys.

Comment: Maybe the issue is not with node client, maybe with Redis itself. What Redis version do you use? Have you observed Redis logs?

Comment: Have you tried using the `TTL` command in redis-cli to see what the time to live on a recently set key is? https://redis.io/commands/ttl/

Comment: @YoavNaaman redis_version:7.0.12

Comment: @SimonPrickett checked numerous TTLs and all have the correct values set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening. Turns out because I had `maxmemory=120mb` the keys were being evicted after I had already called `exists()` and wrote new keys to the cache evicting the the least recently used keys.

Figured this out but observing the `evicted_keys` stat after every data request. Simply increasing `maxmemory` solved the issue.